# $_FILES is empty in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, file, codeigniter

I'm developing a form using CodeIgniter. In this, one of the fields is to upload a file. I followed some tutorials about file uploading in CodeIgniter successfully, but, in my work, the $_FILES is always empty, and I can't see why. I'm a newbie in this framework.

The view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            $this->load->helper('form');
            echo form_open_multipart($action); ?>
            Área:
            <select>
                <option value="1">Teste 1</option>
                <option value="2">Teste 2</option>
            </select> <br>

            Data de abertura: <input type="text" id="data_abertura" placeholder="tqv"> <br>

            Prioridade:<br>
            <input type="radio" name="prioridade" value="3">Alta<br>
            <input type="radio" name="prioridade" value="2">Média<br>
            <input type="radio" name="prioridade" value="1">Baixa<br>

            Anexar arquivo: <input type="file" accept="image/*, text/*, .doc, .docx, .pdf" name="arquivo" id="arquivo"><br>

            Descrição: <br><textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="descricao" name="descricao"></textarea><br>
            <input type="submit" id="enviar" name="enviar" value="Enviar">
         <?php echo form_close() ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

The controller:

> ```
> <?php 
> class c_Formulario extends CI_Controller {
> public function __construct() 
> {
>     parent::__construct();
>     $this->load->helper('url');
> }
>
> public function index()
> {
>     $data['action'] = site_url('c_formulario/inserir_dados');
>     $this->load->view('v_formulario', $data);
> }
>
> public function inserir_dados()
> { 
>     $config['upload_path'] = './upload/';
>     $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|doc|docx|pdf|txt';
>     $config['max_size'] = '100';
>
>     $this->load->library('upload');
>     $this->upload->initialize($config);
>     var_dump($_FILES);
>
>     foreach($_FILES as $field => $file)
>     {
>         //var_dump($_FILES); die();                
>         // No problems with the file
>         if($file['error'] == 0)
>         {
>             // So lets upload
>             if ($this->upload->do_upload($field))
>             {
>                 $data = $this->upload->data();
>                 echo $data['full_path'];
>             }
>             else
>             {
>                 $errors = $this->upload->display_errors();
>                 var_dump($errors);
>             }
>         }
>     }
>
>     $this->load->model('m_formulario', '', TRUE);
>
>     $area = array('id' => null, 'nome' => $this->input->post('area', TRUE));
>     $data = array('id' => null, 'dataabert' => $this->input->post('data_abertura', TRUE));
>     $prioridade = array('id' => null, 'nome_prioridade' => $this->input->post('prioridade', TRUE));
>     $arquivo = array('id' => null, 'urlarquivo' => $this->input->post('arquivo', TRUE));
>     $descricao = array('id' => null, 'descricao' => $this->input->post('descricao', TRUE));
>
>     $dados = array
>     (
>         'area' => $area, 
>         'data' => $data,
>         'prioridade' => $prioridade,
>         'arquivo' => $arquivo,
>         'descricao' => $descricao
>     );
>
>     $this->m_formulario->inserir($dados);
> }
> ```

Thanks any help!

Comment: I don't know exactly why, but changing the allowed types I solved the issue.

> $config['allowed_types'] = '*';

I was testing with some txt and png files. Well, it's ok now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly why, but changing the allowed types I solved the issue. $config['allowed_types'] = '*'; I was testing with some txt and png files. Well, it's ok now. Sorry the bad question.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the correct configuration of all the extensions mime types (pdf,txt,...) in your config/mimes.php file?

If a mime type is missing, you can find the correct ones on google pretty easy ;)